# css media query is not working on :before attribute

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to apply media query on tablet device everything is working inside the media query except the before attribute in which I have to reduce the height this is my CSS code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height:   5% !important;
  }
}
```

this is my HTML

```
<div class="img-wrapper headerimage">
   <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Start Learning With Hifzil" class="img-responsive" >
   <div class="img-overlay align-middle">
      <h1 class="headingBox text-center">Start Learning With Hifzil</h1>
      <h4 class="smallBox text-center">Join Now, Enrolled In Class , Play & Learn</h4>
      <div class="mx-auto d-block btnBox">
         <button class="btn valign">Students, start now</button>
         <button class="btn valign" style="background: #fff;color:#7952b3">Teachers, start now</button>
         <button class="btn valign" style="background: #fff;color:#7952b3">Administration Panel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set height in percentage. For example `5%` of what ? the `img-overlay` div has a specified height ? if not, it will be `5%` of nothing, which results in nothing.

Set a specified height on the `img-overlay` div and it will work. See below ( i added `height:100px` )

Or you can use a height which is not in percentage

```css
 .img-overlay {
   height: 100px
 }
 
 .img-overlay:before {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 15% !important;
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .img-overlay:before {
     height: 5% !important;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper headerimage">
  <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Start Learning With Hifzil" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="img-overlay align-middle">
    <h1 class="headingBox text-center">Start Learning With Hifzil</h1>
    <h4 class="smallBox text-center">Join Now, Enrolled In Class , Play & Learn</h4>
    <div class="mx-auto d-block btnBox">
      <button class="btn valign">Students, start now</button>
      <button class="btn valign" style="background: #fff;color:#7952b3">Teachers, start now</button>
      <button class="btn valign" style="background: #fff;color:#7952b3">Administration Panel</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still not working i have tried the output is same as before applying media query

Comment: How you become ensure that '.img-overlay' have no content? It is not always important to set height if have content.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra well. as you can see in my example...it works. can you share full relevant code?

Comment: i am making a fiddle

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra in your fiddle, the height is changing. What is the problem ?